# Looping through all the document libraries and modify the items

Tags: 2007, development, list, site-collection, web

I have here a piece of code which loops through the all site collections and webs and lists to find particular and modify some items:

```
foreach (SPSite site in webApp.Sites)
                {
                    foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                    {
                        SPFeature feature = web.Features[new Guid(strGuid)];

                       if (feature == null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        //Feature is activated, proceed!

                        //Loop through all the lists in web
                        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                        {
                            if (!(list is SPDocumentLibrary))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (list.Fields.ContainsField(strFieldName))
                            {
                                //TODO, modify set of items
                            }
                        }     
                    }
                }
```

But I have an issue on first time when it gets to `if (!(list is SPDocumentLibrary))` it jumps out and out ... anyone has any idea why?

Or is my approach wrong and something goes wrong?

I don't get any errors tho, but it is as if the collections are empty, but it isn't, there are still plenty of webs and lists to check out.

PS: it is in sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 1):

you can check whether splist is document library or not by using following condition.

if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
{
}